# What happens to a cURL session when the user aborts my script?

Tags: php, curl

In my PHP script, I am calling a REST API method using cURL:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://somehost/api/somemethod');
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

I know that if the user aborts the request (e.g. by clicking the stop button in the web browser) then my PHP script will terminate immediately.

Will the cURL session also terminate (and abort the request) when the PHP script terminates? If not, what must I do to ensure that aborting the user's request also aborts the cURL request?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean. It's not like the curl request will stay alive somehow, it'll abort sooner or later. Whether PHP will abort it right the millisecond the user cancels or keep the request alive for some time for internal reasons is an implementation detail, which usually shouldn't matter too much since HTTP requests should be relatively quick anyway. What exact concern do you have here, why would it be important to abort immediately?

Comment: @deceze My understanding is that cURL runs in a separate process, so theoretically it could keep on running after the script terminates. I wasn't sure whether PHP killed the cURL process or if it was allowed to run to completion.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly, yes. When the PHP script is terminated by the user the script ends along with everything it was running.

To be sure, take a look at this

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

```
ignore_user_abort(false);
```

> PHP will not detect that the user has aborted the connection until an
>   attempt is made to send information to the client.

Comment: This only applies "when running PHP as a command line script". Bradley talks about "clicking the stop button in the web browser".